# How to pass parameter from console application c# to running process? Using wcf?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, process

I have  application that call `exe` and open process. 
In this process there is a thread that opens few more threads which is do the same. I need to pass some parameter from the application to the interior thread.

How can I do it with wcf?

There are another way?

Comment: Am I mistaken, or are you looking for a way to communicate between separate processes? (Your console application and an already running one.) Or do you start the other process too? Does the communication required to be bidirectional? What does this thing has to do with threading?

Comment: You can use batch bile.Simple batch file will do the work.Take the output(say a) from console in batch file and then call another method from that batch file passing a as an arguement.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to be accomplished ? To just pass your parameter to a new Thread you can use ParametrizedThreadStart. If your parameter is outside of Main thread of your exe app i see two options:

1. If you know what your parameter is at time when you start this exe just pass your parameter into it like myapp.exe /myparam1 /myparam2
2. Host WCF service in that thread and use RPC (remote procedure call) to call some method for example UpdateParamter(object parameter) and pass your parameter in this method as an argument